# Regular expression: how to not select a given world in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have this scenario:

I need to find every urls that not contains http

E.g.:

I can select:

```
<a href="abc123.io"></a>
```

I can't select:

```
<a href="http://abc123.io"></a>
```

I know I can negate a word in regular expression:

```
^((?!http).)*
```

But I dont know how to select the  without the http://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<a href="(?!http://)([^"]*)">
```

Comment: what [^"] means? not " ?

Comment: @felipe Any character except double quote.

Comment: @Georgy Yeah I should've. Don't have time now, will check back later. Cheers!